# Android FileProvider with photo take intent gives a java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i have a problem with new FileProvider API:

I have this code to generate a uri from a file:

```
public Uri generateUri(String authority) {
            File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File imageFile = fileHelper.from(storageDir, PHOTO_NAME);

            if (!imageFile.exists() && !imageFile.createNewFile()) {
                throw new Exception("Can't create capture file");
            }
            Uri sharedUri = ExtendedFileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authority, imageFile);
            return sharedUri;
    }
```

The URI it's correct, and now i open a camera intent like this>

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, result);
                context.grantUriPermission(context.getPackageName(), result,
                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                context.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, BaseActivity.SUBACTIVITY_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
```

Then, camera it's opened, and when photo is taked and confirmed, i have:

```
01-10 15:37:27.236 W/FastPrintWriter: Write failure
                                      java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
                                          at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:501)
                                          at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:316)
                                          at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushBytesLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:336)
                                          at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:359)
                                          at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flush(FastPrintWriter.java:394)
                                          at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.dumpGfxInfo(ThreadedRenderer.java:613)
                                          at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.dumpGfxInfo(WindowManagerGlobal.java:556)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpGfxInfo(ActivityThread.java:1175)
                                          at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:577)
                                          at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
                                       Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
                                          at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
                                          at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:273)
                                          at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:319)
                                          at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:496)
                                          at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:316) 
                                          at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushBytesLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:336) 
                                          at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:359) 
                                          at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flush(FastPrintWriter.java:394) 
                                          at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.dumpGfxInfo(ThreadedRenderer.java:613) 
                                          at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.dumpGfxInfo(WindowManagerGlobal.java:556) 
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpGfxInfo(ActivityThread.java:1175) 
                                          at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:577) 
                                          at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

I have done all manifest changes required to use FileProvider and it was working a week ago..
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
context.grantUriPermission(context.getPackageName(), result,
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

This code says "grant my own app permission to use my own app's data". This is not what you want. If you want to use `grantUriPermission()`, the package name needs to be for the app to whom you are granting permission.

Plus, there are simpler options on newer API levels:

```
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
}
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
  ClipData clip=
    ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "A photo", outputUri);

  i.setClipData(clip);
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
}
else {
  List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList=
    getPackageManager()
      .queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

  for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
    grantUriPermission(packageName, outputUri,
      Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
  }
}
```

Here, I:

- Just use `addFlags()`, if the app is running on Android 5.0+
- Use `ClipData`, if the app is running on Android 4.1-4.4
- Iterate over all possible camera apps and grant the permission to each of them, on Android 4.0 and older

I cover that code snippet more in [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/31/granting-permissions-uri-intent-extra.html).